# PDFBox render image misses content

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, soft-references

When using PDFBox, we encounter an issue where if we call `render` on a PDDocument, it sometimes loses content, such as fonts or certain shapes.

Having dug into this, it looks to be caused by the use of `SoftReference` throughout the PDFBox code base. The JVM seems to reap the underlying contents of the PDDocument while it's attempting to render the image. As a result, we see `org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument - Warning: You did not close a PDF Document` at random intervals.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, how was it solved?
So far, our solution has been to write the contents to a file, then read and render.

Comment: The `Warning: You did not close a PDF Document` is just that: A *warning*. Most likely your code simply did what the warning says, *you did not close a PDF document*. The effect of this usually is "merely" that resources are blocked for longer than necessary. In particular this usually does not directly inhibit the code functionality. For your problem rendering PDFs please share a PDF with which one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: The `Warning: You did not close a PDF Document` is printed whenever a `COSDocument` is finalised - such as when it's being GC'd. I'm still using the PDF document, but contents of it are being GC'd before I'm finished, hence my confusion.
It shouldn't affect the code functionality, but during the rendering of an image, certain items disappear such as fonts, because they've been GC'd.

Comment: Please tell what version you are using and share the PDF.

Comment: *"The `Warning: You did not close a PDF Document` is printed whenever a `COSDocument` is finalised"* - generally not, it only is printed if the `COSDocument` has not been explicitly closed before. The `COSDocument` can explicitly be closed by closing the owning `PDDocument`. Maybe you should share enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Any update on this? I am encountering the same issue. Pictures and the footer are missing on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The PDF contained an image which was not rendered. The result was just a plain white BufferedImage.

Including the JBIG2 library (see https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html) to my classpath and updating the PDFBox-version from 2.0.15 to 2.0.26 solved the issue for me.